# Error when trying to log in using TKINTER and MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter

When I try to log in, theres this problem: mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector
import os
import ctypes

from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

 #Aplicação
def login():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host = "localhost",
      user = "root",
      passwd = "123",
      database = "register"
      )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND  password = ?", userEntry, passEntry)

    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()


    for x in myresult:
      print(x)


global screen
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("300x150")
screen.title("Dont Mind Us")
screen.resizable(False, False)
Label(text = "Dont Mind Us", bg = "grey", width = "150", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 15)).pack()
Label(text = "").pack()

#Labels e Entries
userLabel = Label(screen, height = "1", width = "15", text = "Username: ",font = ("Century Gothic", 10))
userLabel.place(x=2, y=70)
userEntry = ttk.Entry(screen, width = 15)
userEntry.place(x=100, y=72)

passLabel = Label(screen, height = "1", width = "15", text = "Password: ",font = ("Century Gothic", 10))
passLabel.place(x=2, y=100)
passEntry = ttk.Entry(screen, width = 15, show = "*")
passEntry.place(x=100, y=102)

#Botoes
loginButton = ttk.Button(screen, text = "Login", width = "15", command = login)
loginButton.place(x=200, y = 125)



screen.mainloop()
```

I just want to search my MySQL database for username and password that already exists and then log in into the application;
Thanks for the help

Comment: You should use `userEntry.get()` and `passEntry.get()` in `mycursor.execute(...)`.

Comment: Did that, and it keeps getting the same error

Comment: I think the posted code is not the same as your original one.  If you really get such error, I suspect that you are calling `mycursor.fetchall()` more than once.

Comment: Actually, the error was the lack of parentheses in : ,(userEntry, passEntry). I dont know why, but he wasnt logging in without this